# Solution for $\int_0^\infty e^{-(ct)^\alpha} \cos(x t) dt$

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the integral:
$\int_0^\infty e^{-(ct)^\alpha} \cos(x t) dt$, where $\alpha$ and $c$ are parameters.

This integral arises from trying to solve for the probability density for a [symmetric $\alpha$-stable probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#Definition).

Can this integral be expressed in terms of some special functions, or at least does it have a ready-made numerical solution method?

Comment: I do not think these can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: For $\alpha = 0, 1, 2$, you can use Fourier Transform tables and Fourier Transform theorems.  For other values of $\alpha$, I have no idea.

Comment: Why not using the imaginary description to define the sum of two exponents and calculate the two resulting integrals?

Comment: I believe that if $\alpha$ is an even natural number you can employ Feynman’s Trick. For non natural numbers, I’m not sure it has a closed from solution.  I can post the Feynman trick method if you would like?